# How can I realize 280qps between memcached client and server?

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I choose Spymemcached as a memcached java client as I find it's set method with no reply seems to be ten times quicker then other memcached clients.

my code:

> memcachedClient.set(key,0,value);

instead of:

> memcachedClient.set(key,0,value).get();

I do care the time cost much more then the set's result.

Now it seems much faster, but it's likely that memory leak occurs on the memcached client.

It tasks about 2G memory for each memcached client process when I run 4 on the same computer with memcached server. And the 8 cores cpu and 4G memory are almost totally consumed. The local net interface 'lo' is only about 0.2Gbits per second.

How can I pull down the cpu and memory consumption rate and even speed up the memcached qps.

I need 280k qps from memcached client, each qps send data with 50B key length and 500B value length. Now I try to start memcached client at local host to avoid the limitation of network interface bandwith. With four memcahced process ,each runs 6 threads, now I can almost realise 180qps, which is far from my target and the cpu and memory turn to be the limitation. And I also need to run storm on the same computer which contains the real java memcached client. So of course I can't allow the memcached clients take up core resources.

How can I reduce the cpu and memory consumption, or how can I realize 280qps between several java memcached clients on a single computer and the distributed memcached server.

Both gets and sets take half of the queries.Maybe I can try getMulti to fetch 50 keys each time. But question is still there.

Expecting your kind replies.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/memcached/n8zLJRyYNY4 for optimizing multi-get queries with memcached.